# Cypress - Can't use custom task in tests when separating the infra from tests

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, automation, cypress

I've tried to added a new custom task to my plugins file that located outside the tested project.
I've compiled it and configured his path in the `config.json` as well.
All the other plugins from this file it works ok.

The error I got from Cypress during the execution is ->

```
"value": "CypressError: `cy.task('queryDb')` failed with the following error:\n\nThe task 'queryDb' was not handled in the plugins file. The following tasks are registered: log\n\nFix this in your plugins file here:\n./../testilize/cypress/plugins/index.ts\n    at ...
```

[image]

The configuration file is extend to the base config file outside the tested project ->

```
{
  "extends": "./../testilize/cypress.json",
  "baseUrl": "https://www.blabla.com/",
  "env": {
    "client": "https://www.blabla.com/",
    "server": "https://www.blabla.com/"
  },
  "pluginsFile": "./../testilize/cypress/plugins/index.ts",
  "supportFile": "./../testilize/cypress/support/index.js",
  "fixturesFolder": "e2e-tests/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "e2e-tests/test-files"
}
```

plugins file ->

```
// cypress/plugins/index.ts
/// <reference types="cypress" />

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */

const preprocess = require('./preprocess');
const deepmerge = require('deepmerge')
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './../testilize/.env' , override: true })
import { my_connection } from '../support/db-handlers/connections';

function queryTestDb(query, config) {
    // start connection to db
    my_connection.connect();
    // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        my_connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else {
                my_connection.end();
                // console.log(results)
                return resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    require('cypress-log-to-output').install(on)

    on('task', {
        log (message) {
            console.log(message)
            return true
        }
    })

    const configJson = require(config.configFile)
    if (configJson.extends) {
        const baseConfigFilename = path.join(config.projectRoot, configJson.extends)
        const baseConfig = require(baseConfigFilename)
        console.log('merging %s with %s', baseConfigFilename, config.configFile)
        configJson.env.my_db_name = process.env.my_DB_NAME;
        configJson.env.my_db_host = process.env.my_DB_HOST;
        configJson.env.my_db_user = process.env.my_DB_USER;
        configJson.env.my_db_password = process.env.my_DB_PASSWORD;
        configJson.env.my_db_port = process.env.my_DB_PORT;

        return deepmerge(baseConfig, configJson);
    }

    on("file:preprocessor", preprocess);

    on('before:browser:launch', (browser , launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
            launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--window-size=1920,1080');
            return launchOptions
        }
    })

    // Usage: cy.task('queryDb', query)
    on('task', {
        'queryDb': query => {
            return queryTestDb(query, config);
        }
    });

    return configJson
}
```

Test file ->

```
/// <reference types="./../../../testilize/node_modules/cypress" />

let allProjectIDs: any = [];


describe('Tests', () => {

  it('send graphQL request for internal api', () => {
    cy.task(
        'queryDb',
        `SELECT project_id FROM table_name LIMIT 100;`
    ).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      allProjectIDs.push(res);
      console.log(allProjectIDs);
    });
    
  });

});
```

**Stack::**

TypeScript 4.6

Node 14x

Cypress 9.6

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have two `on('task', {` sections in plugins.

The first one looks like the default supplied by Cypress, try commenting it out.